# Logit scale in Plotly Express

Tags: matplotlib, plotly, plotly-python

My goal is to get a probability plot with the logit scale using Plotly Express (px).

In Matplotlib (plt) this is possible:

```
x, y = ([1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
ax.set_yscale("logit")
```

[image: Matplotlib logit plot]

Is there any comparable functionality in px?

The workaround I am trying currently is to get these ticks from plt and give them as parameters to px. That does work, but only changes the tick labels, not the actual scale of the y axis:

```
ytickvals = ax.get_yticks()
fig = px.scatter(x, y)
layout = dict(
    yaxis=dict(
        tickmode="array",
        tickvals=ytickvals
    )
)
fig.update_layout(layout)
```

[image: px plot with good y tick labels but bad y scale]

**How can I set the scale of the Plotly plot to be like the logit scale of Matplotlib?**

Plotly API documentation doesn't know the term "logit" and `plotly.graph_objects.layout.YAxis` seems to not have a way of setting the scale.

PS, bonus question: why do my ticks not get displayed with the suffix using `ticksuffix=" %"` and `showticksuffix="all"`?